# How to call php Service from visual studio with "Add Service Reference"

Tags: c#, php, addition, service-reference

I want to consume a php service from c# desktop application.I added php service to my project via "Add Service Reference" and I can't see correct response that come from method.That is php service wsdl;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:tns = "urn:Invest"
    xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    targetNamespace = "urn:Invest">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault = "qualified" targetNamespace = "urn:Invest">
            <xsd:import namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <xsd:import namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
            <xsd:complexType name = "ReturnItems">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        name = "itemName"
                        type = "xsd:string"
                        minOccurs = "0"
                        maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name = "ShowDataRequest">
        <part name = "no" type = "xsd:string"/>
        <part name = "user_name" type = "xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name = "ShowDataResponse">
        <part name = "return" type = "tns:ReturnItems"/>
    </message>
    <portType name = "InvestPortType">
        <operation name = "ShowData">
            <input message = "tns:ShowDataRequest"/>
            <output message = "tns:ShowDataResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name = "InvestBinding" type = "tns:InvestPortType">
        <soap:binding style = "document" transport = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name = "ShowData">
            <soap:operation soapAction = "urn:Invest#ShowData" style = "rpc"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use = "literal" namespace = "urn:Invest"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use = "literal" namespace = "urn:Invest"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name = "Invest">
        <port name = "InvestPort" binding = "tns:InvestBinding">
            <soap:address location = "http://test.com.tr/service.php"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

When I call ShowData method  from vs2010 via"Add Service Reference" response type is String[] and always return string[0].In addition to I call this method with the same parameter in SoapUi.Return to me as a result of the following;

Request SoapUi:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn = "urn:Invest">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:ShowData>
        <no>475</no>
        <user_name>7302AEKI</user_name>
    </urn:ShowData>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Response SoapUi:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:ShowDataResponse xmlns:ns1 = "urn:Invest">
        <return>
            <item>
                <TAP>
                    <kod>
                        <item>768</item>
                    </kod>
                </TAP>
            </item>
            <item>
                <BASV>
                    <SUB>10</SUB>
                </BASV>
            </item>
            <item>
                <BASV>
                    <SIRK/>
                </BASV>
            </item>
            <item>
                <BASV>
                    <BASV_NO/>
                </BASV>
            </item>
            <item>
                <aaa>bbb</aaa>
            </item>
        </return>
    </ns1:ShowDataResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

As a result is it possible to call this service from VS2010 via "Add Service Reference" or what should be?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the WSDL and the actual response do not match. To get the response you expect fix either the WSDL or the response.